# Codeigniter using different function's where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I have a Postgres database with a table for `orders` and a table `order_contents`, which includes all items of the `order`, and the `order_id`. I'm trying to make a view with order history.

In my model I have two functions, one to retrieve orders, and another to retrieve all the contents of an order, like so:

```
function retrieve_orders($userID){
    $query = $this->db->get('orders');
    $this->db->where('user_id', $userID);
    return $query->result_array();
}

function get_order_contents($orderID){
    $query = $this->db->get('order_contents');
    $this->db->where('order_id', $orderID);
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

So in my controller I call `retrieve_orders()` and pass the resulting array to the view. In the view, I want to create an HTML table for each order with all it's contents. So I iterate through each order and call get_order_contents in the loop.

Everything should work, however what happens is this error shows up in the source:

> Error Number:
>
> ERROR:  column "user_id" does not exist
>   LINE 3: WHERE "user_id" =  '3'
>                 ^
>
> SELECT *
>   FROM "order_contents"
>   WHERE "user_id" =  '3'

As you can see, for some reason, when I call `get_order_contents()` in the view, it uses the where clause I specified for the `retrieve_orders()` function.

What I have done so far is try to manually stop caching, but to no avail. Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: i know this is not the answer - but i think you should create just single query with inner join instead tens queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each function, try to put where() before get().

When you try to get() order_contents it will use where clause from previous where().

Common practice is, use get() at the last call of $this->db after other calls such as where(), etc. See the Active Record documentation in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Chain your db functions like this

```
return $this->db->where('user_id', $userID)
                ->get('orders')
                ->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use `$this->db->get_where()`